# Using Cobra and Viper for a Go CLI

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

I'm creating a CLI in Go and I've decided to use both Cobra and Viper for parsing cli parameters and config files.

I looked all over for a way to use both `cobra` and `viper` to merge both the configuration file and the given CLI parameters.

I've stumbled upon [Sting of the Viper](https://carolynvanslyck.com/blog/2020/08/sting-of-the-viper/) as a way to use `*cobra.Command` flags and automatically load them from a configuration file using `cobra`.

The problem with this implementation is that it forces the configuration keys to have the same exact names as the command parameters. It also doesn't allow me to have more configuration options in the config file.

I've also found [this Github issue](https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/82#issuecomment-403165788). Which also doesn't seems to let me have custom configuration in addition to the CLI flags.

Not finding a suitable solution, I went with the "dirty" route and decided to create a config instance with the cmd flags and one with `viper` and then merge them together using `github.com/imdario/mergo`.

a simplified example:

```
func loadConfigFile(path string) (*Configuration, error) {
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        if _, ok := err.(viper.ConfigFileNotFoundError); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read config file - %s", err.Error())
        }
    }

    var config *Configuration
    if err := viper.Unmarshal(&config); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal config file - %s", err.Error())
    }
}

func loadCmdConfig() *Configuration {
    return &Configuration{...}
}

func loadConfiguration() (*Configuration, error) {
    fileConfig, err := loadConfigFile()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    cmdConfig := loadCmdConfig()

    if fileConfig != nil {
        if err := mergo.Merge(cmdConfig, fileConfig); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return cmdConfig, nil
}
```

Obviously, there are problems with this implementation, so I was wondering if someone knows of a better way to use `cobra` and `viper`.

Comment: Can you explain more the issue you had with the solution you found? "The problem with this implementation is that it forces the configuration keys to have the same exact names as the command parameters." Only because that's how the example is explicitly written; that's not a quality of cobra/viper. "It also doesn't allow me to have more configuration options in the config file." Sure it does. They're held by Viper. Just `v.Get("name")`.

Comment: I want to be able to read a configuration file using viper and to also be able to recieve some parameters as cli flags. I don't want to need to have any correlation between the cli parameter names and the configuration keys.

Comment: Then skip that part. None of that is built-in, the example you linked explicitly adds code to associate the two. Just skip the entire `bindFlags` part from the example.